# C18: Representation of LONG and FLOAT constants in code

Tags: c, types, constants, pic, mplab-c18

Is a special representation needed for `long` and `float` numbers in the code?

In computer programming with C/C++ we put an `f` letter after a `float` typed constant number to distinguish it from `double` type. In C18 language, should/must we do the same thing?

```
float   fPi = 3.14f;  // Do we put this "f" in C18 language?
double dbPi = 3.14;
```

What about the long type?

```
int  iMyInt  = 32767;
long lMyLong = 32768?;  // Do we use any marking for long-type?
```

Comment: `(also known as MPLAB C18) is a full-featured ANSI compliant C compiler`

Comment: Compliant to what version of the ANSI standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mcc18 does a few things slightly different from the ANSI standard:

- integer literals take on the smallest possible type, unless annotated otherwise. So `100` is a `char`, `300` is an `int`, `32768` is a `long`.
- `double` and `float` are the same type; both are software-emulated `32`-bit IEEE floating points.

For both of these points and more info see the [User's Guide](http://gputils.sourceforge.net/51288a.pdf) .